# Sort table header in descending order page wise without sorting whole database table

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to know how to sort a table header only in that page without sorting the whole table.is this possible in cakephp? please show me some sample code. my view is

```
    <?php
                    echo   $url = $this->Paginator->sort('ID', 'id',array('direction' => 'desc'));
                    $arrow = getArrow($url);
                  ?>

This is my Controller:

$this->paginate = Set::merge($this->paginate, array('OrderFinalized' => array(


                        'limit'=>4,
                        'conditions' => $condition_ary,
                                'joins' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'table' => 'order_entry_headers',
                                        'alias' => 'OrderEntryHeaders2',
                                        'type' => 'inner',
                                        'foreignKey' => false,
                                        'conditions' => array('OrderEntryHeaders2.id = OrderFinalized.order_entry_headers_id'),

                                            'order' => array(
'OrderEntryHeaders2.id'=> 'desc'
 )
                ),
```

this is  the query:

```
$result = $this->OrderEntryHeader->query("SELECT (value+1) as val FROM order_entries_seq ORDER BY OrderEntryHeader.id desc ");
```

When I sort the first page desending order I get the last results from the database table.i want to sort only the results from that page.it should not change while navigation.

ex- id name (page 1)  ASC
     1 A
     2 B
     3 C
     4 D

DESC  id name
       4 D
       3 C
       2 B
       1 A

Comment: Please understand how stackoverflow works - if you ask a question and don't get answers: don't ask the same question again **edit it to address _why_ it's not getting answers**.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to retrieve data from a database and then use the sorting. The easiest way is by using JavaScript.

You need front-end / client-side table sorter like

http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

> is it still possible to do with sort function?

It is possible in CakePHP, make [array sort](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::sort) in [afterFind method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind)

Comment: does it support php? is it still possible to do with sort function? in php

Comment: What you want is to retrieve data from a database and then use the sorting. The easiest way is by using JavaScript. It is possible in CakePHP, make array resort in afterFind method http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::sort . But you complicate.